# Is $(\frac{1}{x})\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} \,\cos\frac {1}{x} &\text{if } x>0 \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$

Is this function *continuous*?
My intuition says no because as $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ approaches $\infty$.

Is that a good enough reason?

What about $f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^a$ where $a $ is positive ?

**Added:** I'm sorry I was trying to mean $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\,\cos \big(\frac{1}{x}\big)^c$ where $c $ is positive. Would you please help me with that ?

Comment: I'd answer, but youll just delete the question a second after I do.

Comment: Actually, $f(x)$ does not approach $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$, but $f(x)$ *may* approach $+\infty$. To upgrade intuition into a proof, one needs to give a sequence $x_k$ that approaches 0 while $f(x_k)$ approaches $+\infty$. This is mathbeing's answer below.

Comment: The case is more severe than you think. For $x$ approaching $0$, $f(x)$ approaches every real infinitely many times.

Comment: Please do not change the question when it already has an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is good enough reason. To formalize it just notice that for $f$ to be continuous at $0$ we would need $$0=f(0)=\lim_{k\to+\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{2k\pi}\right)=\lim_{k\to+\infty}2k\pi=+\infty,$$
which is absurd.

For your second question, $f(x)=(1/x)^a=e^{-a\log x}$ is continuous in $(0,+\infty)$ but not at $0$ because $f$ is not bounded near $x=0.$

For your modified second question: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^c$, $c>0$, is also not continuous at $x=0$ because the same reasoning as above applies and leads to the contradiction $0=+\infty.$

Comment: haha, I upvoted this already, now you can't delete. Muahahahaha !!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase my question correctly. I meant if f(x) was = (1/x)^a cos (1/x) would it still be continuous?